# Why does my code return 'No such file or directory: '/Users/robert/Downloads/converted data/D2_24.0.SSC.txt'. why I use file.cmp() function in python?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egko5.png)

I am using filecmp.cmp() to compare the two files. But not sure why it returns the error  No such file or directory: '/Users/robert/Downloads/converted data/D2_24.0.SSC.txt'. All files are valid and in the same folder. Please help.

Transcribed from image:

```py
import filecmp

file1 = '/Users/robert/Downloads/converted data/D2_24.0.SSC.txt'

# Path of second file
file2 = '/Users/robert/Downloads/converted data/D6_15.0.SSC.txt'

# Compare the os.stat()
# signature i.e the metadata
# of both files
comp = filecmp.cmp(file1, file2)

# Print the result of comparison
print(comp)
```

Results in FileNotFoundError.

Comment: What's the output of `import pathlib; p1 = patlib.Path(file1); print(p1.exists()); print(p1.parent.exists()); print(list(p1.parent.iterdir()))`?

Comment: For future reference, please don't post images of your code - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: What OS are you using, and show a file listing that shows the files.

Answer (score 1):

Change the filepaths from `"/Users/robert/Downloads/converted data/D6_15.0.SCC.txt"` to a correct full filepath of `"C:\\Users\\robert\\Downloads\\converted data\\D6_15.0.SCC.txt"` (and the same changes for the other filepath).  (I am assuming you are using Windows.)

Relative filepaths will work, but they need to be correct relative to your current working directory (use `os.getcwd()` - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd for documentation).